# "Cost fordest" and "Porded point" - meanings of terms

Tags: machine-design, terminology, cost-estimation, engineering-economics

Not so long ago in our organization there was a seminar on machine-building issues related to parallel robots. The seminar was attended (in a remote format) by an Iranian-speaking colleague who spoke from Tehran. But that's not the point. He uttered two terms: "cost fordest" and "porded point". I heard them in this way, as the level of the speaker's English, unfortunately, left much to be desired.

Googling these terms did not give me answers to the question of what these terms mean. A colleague left contacts, but has not responded to the e-mail for 4 days. I'm very interested to know if anyone has heard anything similar to these terms "cost fordest" and "porded point"? Something to do with pricing and graphics, most likely...

**Context:**

After some discussion of the question in the comments, I realized that the *first term* is "Cost forecast". This is very close to the context and it was just about this problem.

As for the *second term*, I think when he was talking about "porded point", the slides showed graphs similar to these

[image]

And this "break-even point" is very suitable in terms of what he was talking about. But the pronunciation of his "porded" (I remember it clearly) is not at all like "break even" ... Maybe there is some kind of economic section of project management similar to "porded"? Nothing comes to my mind. "Recorded point", "Reported point" ... no, I doubt it. Most likely, it was just about the term, in meaning close to the "break-even point".

It seems that up to this point the speaker has been leading up to the problem of the transition point to making a profit from the introduction of new devices, and then he talked about what evaluation methods are provided by project management and that if the new development has not yet been widely adopted in the industry, then it requires the formation of a large experience in its development and cost assessment !!! to develop statistically significant measures of work

Comment: I would be looking to "guess" the meaning of those terms based on the context in which they were used. So what was before and after those words? You might need to go plus / minus 5 minutes in your notes.

Comment: "cost forecast" may b e a possibility... but without the context it is a WAG...

Comment: @SolarMike Exactly! The first term is 100% "cost forecast"

Comment: @SolarMike I'll try to add some context... I think when he was talking about "porded point", the slides showed graphs similar to these. https://www.pmi.org/kasimage/dca49aa5-630d-49f9-b9c8-ab38d9f406f6/image09.jpg And this "break-even point" is very suitable in terms of what he was talking about. But the pronunciation of his "porded" (I remember it clearly) is not at all like "break even" ... Maybe there is some kind of economic section of project management similar to "porded"? Nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: Wild guess: recorded or reported point.

Comment: Are you sure the first one wasn't "post-Fordist"?

Comment: @dtn did you mean to address me with the comment about reported point or recorded point or do you think you should be addre4ssing Fred?

Comment: @SolarMike yes, my comment was addressed to Fred, I made a mistake

Comment: @DanielHatton I am sure that the first term was exactly "cost forecast" at 100%

Comment: @Fred "recorded point", "reported point" ... no, I doubt it. Most likely, it was just about the term, in meaning close to the "break-even point".

Comment: This question does not belong here.  Without the context of the previous minute and next minute, pointless to guess.  Some of your comments should be added to the question.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I did some editing

Comment: Either way, the collective we cannot answer the question and it is not about engineering so it must be closed.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat And yet, theoretical economists cannot give an exact answer to my question.  While modern engineers, who in one way or another more often and more closely deal with economic issues in practice, at the very least, but were able to give a good hint.